# Memory leak when inserting into MySQL with Powershell v4

Tags: mysql, database, powershell, memory

I'm using powershell v4 on W2K12 R2 (fully patched) to insert a large number(100+ million) of records into a MySQL database. I've run into a bit of a problem where memory usage continues growing and growing despite aggressively removing variables and garbage collecting. Note that the memory usage is growing on the box that I'm running the script on  -not the DB server.

The insertion speed is good and the job runs fine. However, I have a memory leak and have been beating my head against a wall for a week trying to figure out why. I know from testing that the memory accumulates when calling the MySQL portion of the script and not anywhere else.

I've noticed that after every insertion that the memory grows from anywhere between 1MB and 15MB.

Here is the basic flow of the process (code at the bottom).
-records are being added to an array until there are 1,000 records in the array
-once there are a thousand records, they are inserted, as a batch, into the DB
-the array is then emptied using the .clear() method (I've verified that 0 records remain in array).
-I've tried aggressively garbage collecting after every insert (no luck there).
-also tried removing variables and then garbage collecting. Still no luck.

The code below is simplified for the sake of brevity. But, it shows how I'm iterating over the records and doing the insert:

```
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText($filetoread)
$lineCount = 1
   while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
      if($lineCount -ge 1000-or $reader.Peek() -lt 0) {

          insert_into_db

          $lineCount = 0
      }
   $lineCount++
   }
$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()
```

One call to establish the connection:

```
[void][system.reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector Net 6.8.3\Assemblies\v4.5\MySql.Data.dll")
$connection = New-Object MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection($connectionString)
```

And here is the call to MySQL to do the actual inserts for each 1,000 records:

```
function insert_into_db {
    $command = $connection.CreateCommand()                  # Create command object
    $command.CommandText = $query                           # Load query into object
    $script:RowsInserted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()       # Execute command
    $command.Dispose()                                      # Dispose of command object
    $command = $null
    $query = $null
}
```

If anyone has any ideas or suggestions I'm all ears!

Thanks,
Jeremy

Comment: Have you tried creating and disposing the connection object every 1000 rows to see if it affects memory leak?  Not most efficient use of resource, but may provide information (and if useful, you could adjust to recreate the connection every 100k rows or something).

Comment: Actually, no. I haven't tried that. I definitely agree that is not a very good use of resources but I'll give it a shot in little bit. I can't imagine though that people would put up with something like this. So, it still has me wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I just gave it a try. I tried it both with and without connection pooling. Without connection pool it spun up a huge number of connections, and with pooling it died shortly after it reached the pool max. Neither option will really work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial conclusion about the problem being related to the Powershell **-join** operator appear to be wrong.

Here is what I was doing. Note that I'm adding each line to an array, which I will un-roll later when I form my SQL. (On a side note, adding items to an array tends to more performant than concatenating strings)

```
$dataForInsertion =  = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
$reader = [IO.File]::OpenText($filetoread)
$lineCount = 1
   while ($reader.Peek() -ge 0) {
      $line = $reader.Readline()
      $dataForInsertion.add($line)
      if($lineCount -ge 1000-or $reader.Peek() -lt 0) {

          insert_into_db -insertthis $dataForInsertion

          $lineCount = 0
      }
   $lineCount++
   }
$reader.Close()
$reader.Dispose()
```

Calling the insert function:

```
   sql_query -query "SET autocommit=0;INSERT INTO ``$table`` ($columns) VALUES $($dataForInsertion -join ',');COMMIT;"
```

The improved insert function now looks like this:

```
function insert_into_db {
    $command.CommandText = $query                           # Load query into object
    $script:RowsInserted = $command.ExecuteNonQuery()       # Execute command
    $command.Dispose()                                      # Dispose of command object
    $query = $null
}
```

So, it turns out my initial conclusion about the source of the problem was wrong. the Powershell -join operator had nothing to do with the issue.

In my SQL insert function I was repeatedly calling $connection.CreateCommand() on every insert. Once I moved that into the function that handles setting up the connection (which is only called once  -or when needed) the memory leak disappeared.

Comment: In this usage, `-join` also leaves you wide open to SQL injection-type problems because you're not properly handling your strings - best case, you get invalid SQL. Worst case, the data from your file results in data being dropped from your database. You should be doing a [bulk data import](http://snipplr.com/view/44949/) instead - it'll likely be **far** faster than what you're doing here.

Comment: I certainly agree about the possibility of SQL injection. In this particular case, I exclusively control the data and have scrubbed it thoroughly prior to inserting. Question regarding bulk import  -would it be able to handle large import jobs across unreliable connections? Something in the order of 30+ million records, or would it requires batches?

Comment: I've never done a mysql bulk import, let alone one of that size. If mysql can't gracefully handle an unreliable connection in that scenario, I would definitely suggest splitting it into smaller batches, or transfer the files to a location with a more stable connection and run the import from there.